# How to Iteratively Create Many Tables, Each Named After a List Element, also query iteratively based on list

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyodbc

I want to iteratively create ~1900 tables, using a *for loop*, each one named after a list element.

Each newly created table will contain only rows which meet a simple SQL query, "WHERE Cable_Op = [the same list element mentioned above]".

Essentially, I want a table for each element in my list, that only contains rows where the Cable_Op = that same element.

I have a list of the 1900 elements, each one a text string.

Right now, I'm trying

```
cursor = conn.cursor()

with open("C:/Python27/COALS_CARS/PROVIDERS.txt") as f:
providerlist = f.read().splitlines()

for provider in providerlist:
    cursor.execute('SELECT UID, COUNTY, STATE, Cable_Op into [provider] from COALS where Cable_Op =provider')
```

to no avail. In hours of searching, I've seen neither mention of naming/creating new tables iteratively based on a list, nor querying iteratively based on a list.

Basically, I want a table called "AT&T" that has only values where Cable_Op = "AT&T", a table called "Comcast" that has only values where Cable_Op = "Comcast" and so on (where AT&T and Comcast are list elements).

Does pyodbc allow this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

first a few questions:

- Is this a one time operation? or will it be run every so often and
  the tables reloaded?
- Not to question the purpose, would it better to use the loop to
  create a view on top of the base table for each provider and then the
  data will be current?
- What RDBMS are you using?

If you want to create the tables (if you have the correct permissions)

There are 2 ways to do this:

1. Using: (SQL Syntax)

```
     CREATE TABLE <table name> (<field definitions>)
     -- OR --
     TRUNCATE TABLE <table name> -- If the table already exist clear out the data

     -- Then, load in the data...

     INSERT INTO <table name> (<field list>) SELECT <field list> FROM COALS WHERE Cable_Op = <table name>
```

1. Using: (SQL Syntax)

```
     SELECT <field list> INTO <table name> FROM COALS WHERE cable_op = <table name>
     -- will fail if the table already exists
```

In the for loop
  ...
  check the table exists, if so handle appropiately (truncate and reload or drop)
  Create and load the table

Now with your code snippet, you are not using the text substitutions.
See below (doesn;t check for existance of tables)

```
    import pyodbc


    def main():
        serverName = 'DETAIL'
        databaseName = 'FS001'
        conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};Server=%s;Database=%s;Integrated Security=true;' % (serverName, databaseName))
        cursor = conn.cursor()

        with open("C:\Data\PROVIDERS.txt") as f:
            providerlist = f.read().splitlines()

        for provider in providerlist:
            cursor.execute("SELECT UID, COUNTY, STATE, Cable_Op into [%s] from COALS where Cable_Op = '%s'" % (provider, provider))

        cursor.execute('select * from %s' % 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES')
        rows = cursor.fetchall()
        for row in rows:
            print row

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```